# Baffled by firestore uneven segments error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get some data into a firestore collection from a flutter app like so:

```
onPressed: () {
  _uid = _controller.text.trim();
  Firestore.instance.collection('UserData').document(_uid)
    .setData({
      'uid': _uid
    })
    .then((_) {
      print("user added to UserData");
    }).catchError((e) {
      print("add UserData err: $e");
    });
},
```

But this gives the following error:

> add UserData err: PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but UserData has 1, null)

This is weird since I have a simple coll/doc pair. I'm using the same code structure I'm multiple other places with no problem. Here's how the db looks like:
[image]

Someone please help me sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `_uid` is an empty string.  You'll have to figure out why that is, and check for that case before using it in a document reference.

Comment: Thanks Doug, right as always. Sorry for my silly mistake.